# Derivative of narrowband signals

Tags: derivatives

I just read a statement in an article that "for a narrowband signal $u(t), -\frac{d^2(u)}{dt^2} \sim u(t)$". Is this appropriate? Here, $u(t)$ is a transient displacement field and we are talking about bandwidth of $\sim 1$ octave.
Here we are only talking about the shape of the waveforms not the absolute amplitude differences.

Comment: in term of spectrum, it would mean $\omega^2 U(\omega) \approx U(\omega)$

Comment: thanks, what you are saying makes sense. Then is it appropriate to say double integral [u(t)] ~ – u(t) ? I am guessing it would be incorrect to say this for odd number of derivatives or integrals because it changes the phase of the spectrum by pi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a narrowband signal $u(t)$ centered at angular frequency $\omega$ you can consider it to be about $u(t)=M(t)e^{i \omega t}$ where the modulation $M(t)$ is slowly varying on this scale.  To see what is happening, let $M(t)=e^{i \omega' t}$ where $\omega' \ll \omega$, which is one definition of narrowband.  If you take a derivative, you get $u'(t)=(i\omega + i \omega')e^{i\omega t}e^{i \omega' t}$  We can then ignore $\omega'$ in the sum and get $u'(t)=i\omega u(t)$  Another derivative works the same way, so $u''(t) \approx-\omega^2 u(t)$.  The point is that the derivative accentuates high frequencies, so we can ignore modulation when we take the derivative.  In your equation you should have a factor in frequency squared. This makes the units right and reflects the above.